# Core data Get all none nil objects and filter by to-many

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My DB model looks like this :

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to fetch only the contacts that contains messages and sorted by the most recent message.

so i did :

```
func lastMessagesFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ContactEntity> {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<ContactEntity> = ContactEntity.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "messages.@count > 0")


    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "messages.@max.date", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    request.predicate = predicate
    return request
}
```

but i get crash :

> reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle messages.@max.date'

also tried :

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "messages.date", ascending: false)
let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

but i get crash :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

how can I solve it?
thanks

Comment: Just omit `.@max`. Dates are comparable.

Comment: @vadian i tried, but i get crash `reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`

Comment: Right, my bad. Maybe it's more efficient to fetch the messages sorted with a reasonable fetch limit and get the contacts

Comment: Have you tried to skip the predicate and only have the sort descriptor with the key path `messages.@max.date`. The documentation isn't quite clear, it could be that objects with no messages are ignored.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, same crash